# cocos2d-x: I'm having a EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I'm having a EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1 ...) sometimes code=2 using cocos2d-x.
Getting this error when I do for example:

```
std::cout << this->getChildrenCount() << std::endl;
std::cout << this->getChildrenCount() << std::endl;
```

On this exact code, the first line works but the second gives me the error.

I was trying to reach all the children so I could do a function like "hey, fade all objects to this value", since they're inside a class extending CCNode.

```
void BasicElement::fadeTo(int opacity, float duration)
{
    CCActionInterval* actionTo = CCFadeTo::create(duration, opacity);
    CCArray* pChildren = this->getChildren();
    if (pChildren && pChildren->count() > 0)
    {
        CCObject* pObject = NULL;
        CCARRAY_FOREACH(pChildren, pObject)
        {
            CCSprite* pChild = (CCSprite*) pObject;
            pChild->stopAllActions();
            pChild->runAction(actionTo);
        }
    }
}
```

Already tried to do my own CCArray adding the elements that I addChild but... Same problems persist.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use same CCAction on more than one sprite. For every sprite you should create new action. So you should create the action inside the loop.

```
void BasicElement::fadeTo(int opacity, float duration){

CCArray* pChildren = this->getChildren();
if (pChildren && pChildren->count() > 0)
{
    CCObject* pObject = NULL;
    CCARRAY_FOREACH(pChildren, pObject)
    {
        CCSprite* pChild = (CCSprite*) pObject;
        pChild->stopAllActions();

        //Create the action here
        CCActionInterval* actionTo = CCFadeTo::create(duration, opacity);

        pChild->runAction(actionTo);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: That makes so much sense how the hell didn't i get there?!

Comment: Even though, that is part of the problem. There is another problem since i can't do getChildren() one after another